# Module not found: Can't resolve 'node:fs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a reactjs application

```
 "react": "^17.0.2",
```

and I don't have any errors in the ts or tsx files.

But when I do npm start I still get this error:

```
Failed to compile
./src/features/activities/details/ActivityDetials.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'node:fs' in 'D:\Mijn Documents\UDEMY\DotnetMultimedia\reactActivities\client-app\src\features\activities\details'
```

And of course I googled a lot. And I tried with this in package.json:

```
 "browser": {
    "fs": false
  },
```

But that doesn't fix the problem.

So what I have to change?

So These is my Details:

```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite';
import { link } from 'node:fs';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button, Card, Image } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import LoadingComponent from '../../../app/layout/LoadingComponent';
import { useStore } from '../../../app/store/store';

export default observer(function ActivityDetails() {
  const { activityStore } = useStore();
  const {
    selectedActivity: activity,
    loadActivity,
    loadingInitial
  } = activityStore;
  const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) loadActivity(id);
  }, [id, loadActivity]);

  if (loadingInitial || !activity) return <LoadingComponent />;

  return (
    <Card fluid>
      <Image src={`/assets/categoryImages/${activity.category}.jpg`} />
      <Card.Content>
        <Card.Header>{activity.title}</Card.Header>
        <Card.Meta>
          <span>{activity.date} </span>
        </Card.Meta>
        <Card.Description>{activity.description}</Card.Description>
      </Card.Content>
      <Card.Content extra>
        <Button.Group>
          <Button
            as={Link}
            to={`/manage/${activity.id}`}
            basic
            color="blue"
            content="Edit"
          />
          <Button
            as={link}
            to="/activities"
            basic
            color="grey"
            content="Cancel"
          />
        </Button.Group>
      </Card.Content>
    </Card>
  );
});
```

Comment: do you have node installed? you should be able to run it in interactive mode by just typing `node` into the console

Comment: The application worked before... so yes I have installed node

Comment: hmm curious what is in \src\features\activities\details
is your project on github?

Comment: You made a typo: `Link` and `link` are different and your IDE probably inserted the import for `link` when you tried to use the variable `link`. There is absolutely no reason to import `node:fs` for this.

Comment: Quentin is right, remove `node:fs` import and watch out for IDE suggestions.

Comment: Holy!! Yes, that was the case. Oooh, Just looked over it. Thank you!!